Extract tiff-image from the h5 file
I got the h5-file from MPCCD detector. I want to extract tiff image from the h5-file with the structure as follows
This is my code and the h5-file.
import h5py
file_path = 'hdf5/XRD_1453960.h5'
h5_file = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')

file_structure = {}
def get_structure(name, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, h5py.Dataset):
        file_structure[name] = obj.shape
    else:
        file_structure[name] = 'Group'

h5_file.visititems(get_structure)
file_structure



H5-file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WcvJWuwKEBmHp152JZpCPQTyLVnqBb9/view?usp=share_link
improve my code that I can extract the tiff-image from the h5-file.
